# Filtered Table Resetting Laravel 5

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am creating a table that displays a list of customers and their information. I have a few filters that, when selected, modify the table as needed and do so automatically. But when I click the Filter button underneath to save the filters selected and add them to the URL, the URL changes to the correct address but the table returns to the original table. Any ideas how to have the filters not reset when clicking the filter button?

Comment: Post the code where you've been trying to fix it.

Comment: How are you retrieving the customer data ?